# tzplot package: problems with calculation of area

Tags: tikz-pgf, tzplot

I started to use `tzplot` package in place of `tikz` package. There are a lot of useful shortcuts. But now I have a problem (perhaps is my mistake). From this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\def \N {50} % <-- change to higher/lower number if You want a more/less accurate shading
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize,scale=1.5]
        % axex, grid and ticklabels
        \tzhelplines[thick](-2,-4)(2,2)
        \tzshoworigin
        \tzaxes(-2,-4)(2,2)
        \tzticks{-2,-1,,1,2} % x-ticks
        {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2} % y-ticks
        % plotting
        \clip (-2,-4) rectangle (2,2);
        \def\Fx{.3*(\x)^3-2} % <-- def cubic (F)
        \tzfn\Fx[-2:2]       % <-- naming the path F
        \def\Gx{-2*(\x)^2+2} % <-- def parabola (G)
        \tzfn\Gx[-2:2]       % <-- naming the path G
        \tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0]{2pt}
        \tzdot(P-2){$B$}[0]{2pt}  
        \tzgetxyval(P){\Px}{\Py}% <-- coordinate of first point of intersection between F and G
        \tzgetxyval(P-2){\Qx}{\Qy}% <-- coordinate of second point of intersection between F and G
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{(\Qx-\Px)/\N};
        \def \t {0}; % <-- initial Riemann area
        \foreach \n in {0,1,...,\N}{% <-- loop for shading area
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\Px+\n*\dx};
            \tzvXpointat{Fx}{\x}(R)%{$R_\n$}[b]
            \tzgetxyval(R){\Rx}{\Ry} % <-- IT SEEMS DONT WORK IN THIS CASE
            \tzvXpointat{Gx}{\x}(S)%{$S_\n$}[t]
            \tzgetxyval(S){\Sx}{\Sy} % <-- IT SEEMS DONT WORK IN THIS CASE
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{\t+(\Sy-\Ry)*\dx} %<-- temporary Riemann area
            \draw[blue!50,opacity=.3] (R)--(S);
        }
        \tzfn[very thick,magenta]\Fx[-2:2]
        \tzfn[very thick,cyan]\Gx[-2:2]
        \draw (0,-3.5) node[fill=yellow,font=\ttfamily] {Area|,=\;\t}; % <-- final Riemann area
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have this output:

[image]

With the code I want:...

1. plot the two functions;
2. shade the area between the two functions (I can set the \N parameter for this)
3. calculate one approximate value (Riemann method) of the shaded area.

For the first two points no problem.
For the third point the result is always zero (see in the picture the yellow zone).
If in the same zone I try to print not the area value but anyone of `\Rx`, `\Ry`, `\Sx`, `\Sy` prior calculated I have erros. So I think the problems arise from the calculus of these variables.
Any suggestion? (Sorry for my english)

Note: in the case of figure the value of shaded area must be equal to 7.68 units of area.

Note1: Perhaps one cant use one variable internal to the loop outside the loop! But I cant find one solution...

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you use a wrong syntax for `\tzXpoint*` and `\tzdot`: you cannot add `{2pt}` at the end, so `\tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0]{2pt}` and `\tzdot(P-2){$B$}[0]{2pt}` must be replaced by `\tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0]` and `\tzdot(P-2){$B$}[0]`. Also a few wrongs `;` after some `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Lastly `Area|,` is probably better with `Area\,`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The last part was simply a typo....

Comment: @quark67 I have read your fine comment several time. But always I have the alert to re-read the same comment.  Also after I click on 'Mark all as read'. Why?

Comment: (I only see this today.) In `tzplot`, all dot size options are delimited by parentheses (roughly, at the last part), not curly braces. As `quark67` commented, for example, `\tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0]{2pt}` must be replaced by `\tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0](2pt)`. Or you can use `\settzdotsize` to change the default dot size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your calculation is totally fine, but you run into scoping issues, since everything inside the `\foreach` loop is scoped. So you need to push the calculated value outside the loop using `\global\let` or the like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\def\N{50} % <-- change to higher/lower number if You want a more/less accurate shading
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize,scale=1.5]
        % axex, grid and ticklabels
        \tzhelplines[thick](-2,-4)(2,2)
        \tzshoworigin
        \tzaxes(-2,-4)(2,2)
        \tzticks{-2,-1,,1,2} % x-ticks
        {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2} % y-ticks
        % plotting
        \clip (-2,-4) rectangle (2,2);
        \def\Fx{.3*(\x)^3-2} % <-- def cubic (F)
        \tzfn\Fx[-2:2]       % <-- naming the path F
        \def\Gx{-2*(\x)^2+2} % <-- def parabola (G)
        \tzfn\Gx[-2:2]       % <-- naming the path G
        \tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(P){$A$}[0]
        \tzdot(P-2){$B$}[0]  
        \tzgetxyval(P){\Px}{\Py} % <-- coordinate of first point of intersection between F and G
        \tzgetxyval(P-2){\Qx}{\Qy} % <-- coordinate of second point of intersection between F and G
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{(\Qx-\Px)/\N}
        \def\gt{0} % <-- initial Riemann area (global variable)
        \def\t{0}  % <-- initial Riemann area (local variable inside loop)
        \foreach \n in {0,1,...,\N} { % <-- loop for shading area
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\Px+\n*\dx}
            \tzvXpointat{Fx}{\x}(R) % {$R_\n$}[b]
            \tzgetxyval(R){\Rx}{\Ry} 
            \tzvXpointat{Gx}{\x}(S) % {$S_\n$}[t]
            \tzgetxyval(S){\Sx}{\Sy} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{\gt + (\Sy-\Ry)*\dx} % <-- temporary Riemann area
            \global\let\gt\t % <-- set global variable to new value
            \draw[blue!50,opacity=.3] (R)--(S);
        }
        \tzfn[very thick,magenta]\Fx[-2:2]
        \tzfn[very thick,cyan]\Gx[-2:2]
        \draw (0,-3.5) node[fill=yellow,font=\ttfamily] {Area\;=\;\gt}; % <-- final Riemann area
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I would be careful with defining single-letter macros using `\def` at document level.

Comment: @quark67 Thanks for cleaning up the code! It seems that I only cleaned up the part that was important to solve the issue ... =D

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I suspected (see my Edite in Note1) the origin of my problem but I was inadept to solve it!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Yes, the pgf/Tikz manual add a remark about this (see section 88, page 1001 in the current version): *Note that in each execution of ⟨commands⟩ the ⟨commands⟩ are put in a TeX group. This means that local changes to counters inside ⟨commands⟩ do not persist till the next iteration. (...) You have to add `\global` if you wish changes to persist from iteration to iteration.*. The manual speaks about counters, but it's applicable to other objets too.

Comment: @quark67 Grazie! I forgotten my expertise as young teacher. Now I am 75...old!